# Multinomial sum with positive coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs, multinomial-coefficients

Consider the following sum.
$$
\sum_{ \substack{L_1 L_2 ... L_k :\\ L_1 +... + L_k = N\\  \forall i \, \, \,  L_i > 0  }}\binom{N}{L_1 , L_2 , ... L_k}
$$
It is well known from the Multinomial Theorem that the sum  would   equal $k^N $ if the restriction $L_i>0$ was replaced by $L_i \geq 0$. Is there a closed expression also for the formula above?

Comment: Probably done by inclusion-exclusion. $k^N$ is the number of functions $\{1,2,\dots,N\}\to\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ and your sum counts the number of **onto** functions.

Comment: You probably get $$\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i\binom ki (k-i)^N.$$

Answer (score 1):

We get from first principles the closed form

$$N! [z^N] 
\left(\frac{z^1}{1!} + \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \cdots\right)^k.$$

This is

$$N! [z^N] (\exp(z)-1)^k = k! \times N! [z^N] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}
\\ = k! \times {N\brace k}.$$